# SAS: converting a datetime to date in where clause

Tags: sas

I have a column in a sas dataset that is of datetime 25.6 format; lets call this column datetime. I want to convert it to Date9 format in a where clause and check against a certain date or date variable.

I currently have the following code:

```
proc sql;
Select rowid, name, dob, country
from db.testTable
where cast(datetime as date9.) eq '14sep2014'd
;
quit;
```

I get an error when i run the above code:

> ERROR 22-322: Syntax error, expecting one of the following: !, !!, &, ), *, **, +, ',', -, /, <, <=, <>, =, >, >=, ?, AND, BETWEEN, 
>                 CONTAINS, EQ, EQT, GE, GET, GT, GTT, IN, IS, LE, LET, LIKE, LT, LTT, NE, NET, NOT, NOTIN, OR, ^, ^=, |, ||, ~, ~=.
>
> ERROR 202-322: The option or parameter is not recognized and will be ignored.

I get the same error message if use the following

```
proc sql;
Select rowid, name, dob, country
from db.testTable
where cast(datetime as date9.) = '14sep2014'd
;
quit;
```

Is there a better way to cast a `datetime` to `date9` format in SAS? 
Any help on this will be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In SAS you would use the `datepart()` function to extract the date value from the datetime value:

```
where datepart(datetime) = '14sep2014'd
```

There is no need to specify a format, as it does not affect the underlying value.

Comment: Thanks for this DWAL, this worked for me, I was able to feed a date with datepart() and SAS produced a resultant dataset for me. Appreciate your quick feedback.

Answer (score 1):

A second option, that undoubtedly is slightly inferior to `datepart` unless you have a *really* large dataset (in which it is a bit faster probably as you have a (hopefully) constant on one side of the expression rather than a function call for each iteration), is to use DHMS to make a datetime:

```
data _null_;
  x=dhms('01JAN2010'd,0,0,0);
  put x=;
run;
```

or even use a datetime constant explicitly:

```
data _null_;
  x='01JAN2010:00:00:00'dt;
  put x=;
run;
```

(I would expect them to be of identical timings, as SAS should optimize the first to the second, since it's a constant expression - but who knows).

And on a side note, SAS has two primitive types: numeric and character.  `input` turns character to numeric, and `put` turns numeric to character - the equivalent of `cast`.  Anything else in SAS (e.g., dates) are simply formats applied to numbers (or characters) and have their own special functions (like datepart here).

Comment: It is a bit different in that comparing two datetime values will require that the date and time be equal rather than just the date.